# Colour palette with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In order to produce replicable example I would have to submit shapefile data etc. and that would be cumbersome for you (downloading data etc.) so here is a attempt just by providing the last part and that's about the `ggplot`

Here is sample code:

```
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen","yellow","red"), space = "rgb")
myPal <- cols(11) 

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
   geom_polygon(aes(fill = measure))+    # draw polygons
   coord_equal() +
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(levels(factor(df$measure))))+
   scale_fill_manual(values = myPal)+
   labs(title="mesure level", x="", y="")+
   theme(axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

Basically, I'm trying to apply my own colours to fill the regions by defining the colour range. The above doesn't work as it produces error:

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

EDIT:  This works however:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = measure))+    # draw polygons
  coord_equal() +
  geom_path(color="grey", linestyle=2)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#ffffcc", high = "#ff4444", 
                  space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50",
                  guide = "colourbar")+
  labs(title="measure level", x="", y="")+
  theme(axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank())
```

EDIT2: The `measure` variable is numeric(), and here is how I insert the measure:

```
  df$measure <- as.numeric(round(runif(nrow(df), 0, 1), 1))
```

`dput` is huge so here is str()

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   344858 obs. of  8 variables:
$ long   : num  18 18 18 18 18 ...
$ lat    : num  48.7 48.7 48.7 48.7 48.7 ...
$ order  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ hole   : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
$ piece  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ group  : Factor w/ 80 levels "0.1","1.1","2.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1    ...
$ id     : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
$ measure: num  0.7 0.4 0.8 0.8 0.8 0.2 0.8 0.5 0.2 0 ...
```

Comment: The error message explains quite clearly what is going wrong: one of the variables is a factor variable while ggplot expects a continuous variable. In your case this is probably the `measure` variable.

Comment: Jaap is spot on and you could have provided a `str(df)` (or `dyplyr::glimpse(df)`) w/o causing too much angst here. For future reference, the functions in R that read-in shapefiles (`readOGR` et al) have a tendency to make factors out of all the strings in the `@data`  portion of the `Spatial…` object.

Comment: I have updated the question and thank you for looking into this and for your patience.

Comment: @Hennik: Thank you, works great!

Comment: If you want a continuous sequential scale, might I beg you to use the `scale_` functions in the github version of [viridis](https://github.com/sjmgarnier/viridis) (the update will be on CRAN soon) instead? It's much easier on the eyes and won't be unreadable by folks with various types of colorblind conditions. Plus it downgrades to grayscale (i.e. printing) quite nicely. It's also way more accurate than `scale_fill_gradientn`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep. `scale_fill_gradient` is continuous. `scale_fill_manual` is discrete and `measure` definitely is numeric (and not a factor) so what you're seeing is totally expected behavior. Here's a toy example to help explain:

```
library(rgdal)
library(curl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# get a simple shapefile

map_url <- "https://andrew.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=us_states_hexgrid&q=SELECT+*+FROM+andrew.us_states_hexgrid&format=geojson&api_key="

res <- curl_fetch_disk(map_url, "hexes.json")

hex <- readOGR("hexes.json", "OGRGeoJSON")

## OGR data source with driver: GeoJSON 
## Source: "hexes.json", layer: "OGRGeoJSON"
## with 51 features
## It has 6 fields

str(hex@data)

## 'data.frame':    51 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ cartodb_id: int  1219 1217 1218 220 215 228 232 227 230 229 ...
##  $ created_at: Factor w/ 4 levels "2015-05-13T22:02:22Z",..: 4 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ updated_at: Factor w/ 51 levels "2015-05-14T14:17:56Z",..: 20 40 47 12 44 2 3 11 19 25 ...
##  $ label     : Factor w/ 51 levels "A.K.","Ala.",..: 20 40 47 12 44 2 3 11 19 25 ...
##  $ bees      : num  60.5 47.8 33.9 13.9 46.3 48.1 42.9 34.9 44.3 38.7 ...
##  $ iso3166_2 : Factor w/ 51 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 22 40 47 12 44 2 4 11 19 26 ...
```

We'll use `bees` since it's similar to your `measure`.

```
# make it so we can use the polygons in ggplot

hex_map <- fortify(hex, region="iso3166_2")

str(hex_map)

## 'data.frame':    357 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ long : num  -133 -130 -130 -133 -135 ...
##  $ lat  : num  55.3 54.4 52.5 51.6 52.5 ...
##  $ order: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
##  $ hole : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
##  $ piece: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
##  $ group: Factor w/ 51 levels "AK.1","AL.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
##  $ id   : chr  "AK" "AK" "AK" "AK" ...
```

By default, `bees` will be considered a continuous variable and the default fill color scale will reflect that:

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex_map, map=hex_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex@data, map=hex_map, aes(map_id=iso3166_2, fill=bees))
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

You can have ggplot use automatic cuts & a discrete colormap vs a continuous colormap with `scale_fill_distiller`:

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex_map, map=hex_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex@data, map=hex_map, aes(map_id=iso3166_2, fill=bees))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_distiller()
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

You can also do a manual cut outside of the ggplot operations and pass that new column into `scale_fill_manual`.

If you *must* use a continuous color scale, *please* consider using the viridis colormap:

```
devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis")
library(viridis)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex_map, map=hex_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=hex@data, map=hex_map, aes(map_id=iso3166_2, fill=bees))
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

It's more accurate in general, accurately visible to the colorblind & downgrades to grayscale well (and accurately).

Answer (score 1):

With `scale_manual` you "[c]reate your own discrete scale" (`?scale_fill_manual`). Thus, the error "Error: Continuous value [i.e. "measure"] supplied to discrete scale [`scale_fill_manual`]".

You need a continuous scale and tried `scale_fill_gradient`. Fine. However, it would be to easier achieve your desired palette using `scale_fill_gradientn`, which creates a "Smooth colour gradient between n colours".

A much simpler example:

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:11, y = 1)

# an analogue to your failed attempt 
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_point(pch = 21, size = 20) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = myPal)
# Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale


# using the continuous scale_fill_gradientn instead, with the desired color vector and space
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = x)) +
  geom_point(pch = 21, size = 20) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkgreen", "yellow", "red"), space = "rgb")
```

[image]

Comment: First I thought this is typo `scale_fill_gradientn` with the `n` on the end :) didn't know about this of course, really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, it is easy to get lots among all the `scales`. When in doubt, I often browse [the output of all help examples](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/).